# Translate binary characters to a human readable string?

Tags: character-encoding, binary-data

So let's say we have a string that is like this:

```
‰û]M§Äq¸ºþe Ø·¦ŸßÛµÖ˜eÆÈym™ÎB+KºªXv©+Å+óS—¶ê'å‚4ŒBFJFó’‰šÒ®}Fó†ŽxöÒ&‹¢ T†^¤( OêIº ò|<)ð
```

How do I turn it into a human readable string of chars, cuz like it was a wierd output of HTML from a webserver that is text I think cuz half the web page loaded correctly.  Do I need to read it with like C or Python or something.  That's only a snippet of the string.

Comment: You're going to have to explain how you want to map that into a readable string.

Comment: `function rewriteString(str) { return "Hello, World"; }`

Comment: Looks like binary data to me... unless it's mojibake. It very much resembles what happens when you do `cat` on a program by mistake on Unix, and it floods the console with sweet binary goodness.

Comment: fyi - these are not binary characters. in fact there's not such a thing called "binary characters". either binary string, a string consisting of 0s and 1s, or binary, numerical representation.

Comment: Dammit! How did you find my GMail password?!

Comment: I'm human, I can read those characters.

Comment: Sure you can read them, but can you *pronounce* them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is in fact *supposed* to be a human-readable string, you'll need to figure out what [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) it uses and translate. It's also possible that the string is compressed, encrypted, or represents binary data. It would be helpful to know where you got your string from.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your web server isn't sending the correct mime-type.  I'd suggest taking a look at the http headers using Firefox's Live Headers plugin.  If a web server decides to send you a pdf, but doesn't set the mime-type, you'll just see garbage on your screen. Alternatively, save the page to a file, and then run these commands from Cygwin or a unix shell:

```
file mypage.htm
strings mypage.htm
```

The first will tell you if the header bytes follow any recognizable pattern.  The second will strip out and display all the human readable text.